# How to remove bots from my computer?

Tags: anti-virus, bots

Because trend micro's rubotted detected that there is a bot running on my system and recommends to run Trend micro's house call to remove the bot.
But when I ran house call, it does not detect anything. By the way,my current antivirus software is Microsoft Security Essentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite way to remove any sort of malware is to start by using [Spybot Search and Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html), and then use [Microsoft/Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to remove the rest -

(Autoruns does not usually "Delete" any files, but completely stops anything/everything from running.)

Anything that this method does not remove most likely has crawled in to the deep parts of your system - usually - to the point, that even if they can be removed, you wouldn't want them to as it could lead to problems later on... At this point, a re install is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is time to abandon MSE. I have heard very few positive things about its ability to detect threats. Your best bet would be to try out some top notch [antivirus](http://www.sophos.com) software (grab some free demos) and see which one best fits your system and your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have a Virus, i wouldn't trust anything on the system.

I'd use a antivirus livedisk ([unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) has a few options in it if you don't want to burn a disk. else [avira](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html) comes to mind

i'd suggest [malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) if you want to scan in windows and don't want the live cd route